# Use log4net in SDK

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, log4net

I am providing an SDK using C#. To enable field debugging, I want to include logging using log4net. How to enable configuration without using App.config since the assembly will be a dll?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using XmlConfigurator to configure a standalone config file location for log4net. You can use this technique to supply independent file-based configuration without having to touch app\web.config, or having to hard-code it. Example:

http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/07/ConfiguringLog4NetForWebApplications.aspx

**Update**

Try the following bootstrapper to configure the standalone config file. It will construct a full path. Try logging out the path if it still appears to be having problems finding it.

```
public static class LogFactory
{
    public const string ConfigFileName = "log4net.config";

    public static void Configure()
    {
        Type type = typeof(LogFactory);
        FileInfo assemblyDirectory = AssemblyInfo.GetCodeBaseDirectory(type);
        string path = Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory.FullName, ConfigFileName);
        FileInfo configFile = new FileInfo(path);
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(configFile);
        log4net.ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(type);
        log.ToString();
    }
}
```

Call:

```
LogFactory.Configure();
```

Comment: I am trying with the suggestion and nothing is logged. So I step into the source code. Here is why:

Comment: I am trying with the suggestion with the exact steps in the above link and nothing is logged. So I step into the source code. Here is why: 
configElement =System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("log4net") as XmlElement;
The Configure function is still looking for "log4net" section in the application config file which I don't have. Any ideas why it is not picking up my own separate log4net.config file? Thx.

Comment: Yes. I think I should be able to get over by calling log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config")) to specify my config file. But currently the VS buildin unit test framework is not picking up this file.

Comment: @Icerman I have added a config routine to my answer which will construct a full path for the config file.

Comment: Great! And I got the log file created by adding the log4net.config as part of deployment in the unit test attribute. Somehow the log file still empty after I run some tests. Here is the config file (a separate comment since it is big).

Comment: <log4net>
    <logger name="MySDK">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MySDKFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <appender name="MySDKFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Temp\MyLog.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level: - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

Comment: @Icerman The config looks fine although there is no xml declaration. So what is the status - is the config file now being found? It the path correct?

Comment: Yes, I skipped the first two lines because of size: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
The path is good and the file is found and MyLog.txt is created. But no content has been logged to the log after I call Logger.Info("Debug info").

Comment: <log4net>    
 <appender name="MySDKFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Temp\MyLog.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
   <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level: - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
 
 <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="MySDKFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>

Comment: @chibacity That root element made the difference. It worked! Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: @Icerman That's what I suspected. You were using a named logger and not logging to it. I replaced it with a general configuration. Boo ya! Glad to help. I earned that rep fo sho! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can put the configuration in the code, although not recommended.

better ship the dll with external file, or add a code- if the file exists, to use it, if not, use hard-coded configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make your SDK log platform agnostic by providing an abstraction of your logger?  Caliburn.Micro does this, and this article describes how it works and how the client can configure the appropriate logger they wish to use - http://buksbaum.us/2010/08/08/how-to-do-logging-with-caliburn-micro/

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using the Common.Logging for .Net abstraction.

http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/

Common.Logging supports log4net, NLog, and Enterprise Library out of the box. It is easy to write your own adapter to use with Common.Logging if you need to.

This way your SDK becomes logging platform agnostic. Your user would still need an entry in the app.config or web.config to indicate which platform to use, but the platform-specific configuration can still be stored in a separate file.