# How to include log4net for a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to implement logging function into a class library, which is itself referenced in a webservice. I tried to add app.config and did everything needed, but it seems that when an exception is thrown, log4net simply does nothing.

my app.config

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\\mylogfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="test" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config")]
```

in LogManager.cs:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
            (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
public static void WriteLog(Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex);
}
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong? How can I get log4net working for my class library?

Thank you

Comment: how does the code look like where you're calling the WriteLog?

Comment: btw, have you tried setting your level on root to ALL, and try removing all those filters on your RollingFileAppender.

Comment: @Pauli: I tried as you suggested, it still didn't work :)

Comment: I assume you understand that app.config gets renamed to the Assembly name on build?

Comment: I checked bin folder, the app.config holds its name :)

Comment: So what happens when you remove the filters?  If you see log messages, what happens when you put DenyAll before the string match filters.  Why not use log level filters instead?

Answer (score 7):

At runtime, config file is always used from host application, unless declared explicitly. Here in case, web.config is being used not app.cofig. Rather mention some other custom config file name and ensure that file is copied in virtual directory of web service. Also as chibacity said, ensure permission on log file. Better keep it in app_data folder for web service host.

Answer (score 5):

You could use some kind of injection, either you build a simple one like:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void LogInfo(string message);
       .
       .
       .
}
```

And then you just inject something that matches that interface, like a wrapper for log4net or such.

But, I think the most correct thing is to not log in the class library. Why I think so is because the library itself is not the application, your web service is so your web service should decide what to log. If you want to log exceptions just don't catch them in the class library and let your web service handle the logging. This will also make it easier to centralize the logging.

Comment: @Thomas I agree re. using an abstraction, but there are many good reasons why you may want a library to log e.g. diagnostics and auditing. If something is wrong with the library, having diagnostics which can be turned on is a good thing.

Comment: @chibacity: My name is Tomas not Thomas ;). Except from that I agree with you in those aspect, but I do think that it should be kept at a minimum. If something is wrong in the library the exception should tell, and that could be logged higher up in the stack. In an ideal world a library should be a third party (but you can be the third part too) that should be "done". Or are you talking about some other kind of "errors"? Errors that don't throw exceptions?

Comment: Sorry for the name spelling :) I am referring to information that can help to analyse problems that may not be leading to exceptions. Even in cases where there are exceptions it is often useful to have surrounding diagnostics information to see the conditions that lead up to an error. This can be of particular importance in production where software may be being used in cruel and unusual ways ;)

Comment: @chibaciy: But then we are talking about tracing information and not logging. I think that those are two separate things, but that just me. I totally agree with you that it is nice to able to turn on such tracing in a config file.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to the following question:

[Use log4net in SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542184/use-log4net-in-sdk/4542416#4542416)

It has a log configuration routine that will construct a complete path to a log4net config file. As you are in a webservice it my not be looking where you expect for "app.config".

Also make sure that you have permission to write to "D:\mylogfile.txt" from your webservice.