# Can i use log4net in class library?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have created a c# class library, and registerd that as com object in my server.
and am calling the c# methouds using VBscript code.

can i use log4.net to log the information on this scenario?

Comment: I think you can. The question should be how to use it correctly, e.g. what the output target you should use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use it in you class library there no issues in it

check this anwer for detail : [How to include log4net for a class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612817/how-to-include-log4net-for-a-class-library)

Comment: I think the tricky part is the configuration of log4net, not the usage in this scenario. I usually load it via a seperate xml in this scenario.

Comment: @weismat - might be but google will surely resolve config issue..becuase there is no info in question to provide detail about it ...