# Log4Net does not log from a class library

Tags: log4net, class-library

I am working on .NET Framework 4.0 using C# in Windows 7, and trying to log from a class library but it's not working. I'm running my application without errors, but also nothing happens to my log file, neither to my console.

So, here is my code:

This is my `App.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>


  <add key="log4net.config" value="config.log4net"/>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newlineExtra Info: %property{testProperty}%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
        <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
      </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="MyLogFile.txt"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="debug"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
        <stringToMatch value="error"/>
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="MyApplication">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

This is what I put into my `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

This what is at the file i'm trying to log:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


log.Debug("Testing");
```

When i run my program nothing happens. Someone knows why?

Comment: This works for me. Are you placing the code for AssemblyInfo.cs into the library project, or the main project?

Comment: At the library project.

Comment: What's this line for? `<add key="log4net.config" value="config.log4net"/>`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4612954/724591), both the app.config, log4net configuration and the AssemblyInfo.cs configurator needs to be placed in the host application.

Lets say I have project `Console` as a console project that I will run, and `Library` as a Library project. `Console` will need to have an app.config file with the above log4net configuration, and the AssemblyInfo.cs will need the XmlConfigurator code inside of it. `Library` does not need either of these, and will work by using the `LogManager` call.

```
Console                 > This is the project that you will run.
    Properties
        AssemblyInfo.cs > Place [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] here.
    app.config          > Place log4net XML configuration here.
    Program.cs          > Start of application.

Library
    Properties
        AssemblyInfo.cs > Leave this file alone.
    Foo.cs              > Create the private readonly property.
        SomeMethod()    > log.Debug("Test");
```

Comment: If the Console is a project with an interface `ILogService` and Library is a `Log4Net` implementation to the service declared in the Console application, as per the above solution, we have to add reference to Log4Net in Console application. Is it a best practice?

Answer (score 4):

Incase anyone is still looking at this and to add to the previous answers, you need to have instantiated a logger in your host application before you can log from the class library.

Comment: This is my problem.  I am trying to execute a .dll class for an installation script.  It needs to run BEFORE my main app runs.  I think this is why it is not logging.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [log4net documentation for assembly attributes](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_Attributes) it says this:

"Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net
to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to LogManager.GetLogger will cause the attributes on the **calling assembly** 
to be read and processed. **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and
certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**"

When the assembly attributes are defined in a class library - i.e. an external assembly - it gets tricky. Can you use `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(path)` instead?

Comment: I tried to use log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() but then i received this error stack: log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file.